# How to pass javascript variables to a partial as locals ? Rails 4 + Haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, partial, locals

I have a partial wich represent a list of users, i want to make it send a different local for each user selected so to refresh a part of the view with a hidden input taking the value of the local.
I have this in my users partial:

```
  %li
    %a{ :href => "#", :onclick => "test("+user.id.to_s+","+id_current_user+");return false"}
```

And this is the function i am calling:

```
:javascript
   function test(with_user, current_user) {
   $("#messages-list").html('');
   $("#message-new").append("#{escape_javascript(render( partial:'messages/form',:locals => {:recipient_id => "with_user" } ))}");
   };
```

The idea is to send the "with_user" javascript value in the locals of the partial, but i tried everything to make it work. No way ! Any one to help me on this ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think your js is going to run till it hits the client. At this point would you have access to partial files stored on the server?

Comment: No i am getting the good partial with the string "with_user" as a value for recipient_id. I want to make it dynamic with the parameter of the javascript function called

Answer (score 0):

This `$("#message-new").append("#{escape_javascript(render( partial:'messages/form',:locals => {:recipient_id => "with_user" } ))}");` will not work from the browser <del>since it has no idea on how to execute ruby code</del>.

I think you may need to go back and figure out why it needs to be rendered like this in the first place.

#### EDIT

This frustrates the parser. The server is sending markup to the browser only **once** so it will not know of any dynamic javascript variables on the client once it runs. I think there has to be a better way to do this using AJAX.

Comment: Is there any way to make the ruby code understand the "with _user" javascript value ? I need this because i refresh a part of html with the corresponding variable.

Comment: Note: the browser understand the ruby code here and it works, the problem, i dont figure out a solution to make the ruby code understand the javascript value in locals.